# connect with facebook for existing users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am using `omniauth-facebook` gem with devise to authenticate with Facebook in my rails application in my user model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  # immediately get 60 day auth token
  oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("App Key",  "App secrets" )
  new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token
  new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
  new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds
  begin
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.username = auth.info.first_name
      user.lastname =auth.info.last_name
      user.email =auth.info.email
      user.authentication_token = new_access_token 
      user.oauth_expires_at = new_access_expires_at 
      user.save!
    end
  rescue  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  end
end

#interact with facebook
def facebook
  @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(authentication_token)
  block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
  logger.info e.to_s
  nil # or consider a custom null object
end


def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  if session["devise.user_attributes"]
    new(session["devise.user_attributes"], :without_protection=> true) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```

and on my `omniauth_callbacks` controller I have this method:

```
def all
  user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  if user.persisted?
    flash.notice = "Signed in!"
    sign_in_and_redirect user
  else
    session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
alias_method :facebook, :all
```

These methods are used to authenticate user from scratch via Facebook. I need a way to connect existing users with their Facebook accounts not new ones if they registered via normal devise registration method

When an existing user is trying to sign in via `Facebook` the following error occurs:

```
A `NoMethodError` occurred in `omniauth_callbacks#facebook`:

undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass
 app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `all'
```

Comment: r u providing fbid and secret key for authoauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"])

Comment: r u getting the correct response in oauth? means after printing the oauth are the right values?

Comment: yes,,the question I want to authenticate existing users on my app with their facebook accounts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find user by `email` first and just update `provider` and `uid` fields in case he is already exists.

So your `User.from_omniauth` may looks like that:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  # immediately get 60 day auth token
  oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("",  "" )
  new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token
  new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
  new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

  user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first
  unless user
    # in that case you will find existing user doesn't connected to facebook
    # or create new one by email
    user = where(email: auth.info.email).first_or_initialize
    user.provider = auth.provider # and connect him to facebook here
    user.uid = auth.uid           # and here
    user.username = auth.info.first_name
    user.lastname = auth.info.last_name
    user.authentication_token = new_access_token
    user.oauth_expires_at = new_access_expires_at
    # other user's data you want to update
    user.save!
  end

  user
end
```

**upd**:

In case you faced password validation error you can override `User#password_required?` method to skip validation for user's signed in via Facebook.

That behavior described in following [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2?view=asciicast) of RailsCasts

Comment: its working to connect existing user ..but when a new user tried to sign up with facebook  An ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid occurred in omniauth_callbacks#facebook: raised

Comment: You probably missed some required fields. Try to use `binding.pry` to check validation errors or `user.valid?; Rails.logger.info user.errors.messages` to check validation errors.

Comment: the problem mainly on email field

Comment: hm. try to set it explicitly via `user.email = auth.info.email`

Comment: i did that ,gives me the same error also I have the password_required? method on my model

Comment: I tried it on the console it gives me RuntimeError: Could not find a valid mapping for #<User id:49....

Answer (score 1):

Just for add an updated version of the answer for rails 4 and devise 3.4.x

Like this is how an updated omniauth would look like

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    if !where(email: auth.info.email).empty?
      user = where(email: auth.info.email).first
      user.provider = auth.provider # and connect him to facebook here
      user.uid = auth.uid           # and here
      user.save!
      user
    else
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.first_name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        user.avatar = process_uri(auth.info.image) # assuming the user model has an image
      end
    end
  end
```

Just look for user by email, if there is one, just add the provider and uid, if there is not one, just create it as suggested in the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

Comment: This is the best answer so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can have your `from_omniauth` be something like this:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.info.slice(:email)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.username = auth.info.name
      user.description = auth.extra.raw_info.bio
    end
end
```

In this way, if there's an existing user with email same as the facebook account, then the `first_or_create` will return it and then the user can sign in (it won't be update).

Comment: Sorry, forgive about this. In this way the `uid` and `provider` will never be set. And if FB allows users to edit their email without confirmation, then they can change their email and sign in to others' accounts.